# Find the 100th Sorted Number

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Number with two or more digits in which the digits reading left to right occur in strictly increasing order are called as "sorted numbers". For example 125, 14 and 239 are *sorted numbers* while 22, 74 and 198 are *not sorted*. Suppose that a complete list of sorted numbers is prepared and the numbers themselves are written in increasing order, *what will the 100th sorted number on the list be?*

The options are 389, 356, 345, and 258.

Can please anyone solve this and give me an explained answer and concept used?

Comment: Please rewrite the question in proper english so that we can actually understand what it is about. Also provide context about what you have tried, what you know about the problem and where you get stuck.

Comment: Maybe $25$ is sorted number?

Comment: 25 seems a sorted number, according to the definition geven before. Did you mean '22 is not sorted'...?

Comment: I would start by working out how many one-digit numbers are sorted and how many two-digit numbers are sorted.  You will then have a good "road map" to discovering how far into the three-digit numbers one needs to go to find the hundredth sorted number.

Comment: yes @CiaPan 22 is not sorted

Comment: @hardmath one digit number cannot be classified into sorted numbers.. only numbers with 2 or more digits can be classified into sorted numbers

Comment: @OveAhlman can you please tell what aren't you getting in the question?? and I have reached nowhere till now.. as I cannot manually list the sorted numbers upto 100 .. I am not able to get any method that will help me do so

Comment: You are correct, so there are zero one-digit sorted numbers.   Only one hundred left to go!

Comment: But I have 4 options to choose from. I didn't mentioned them in the question because it may make the question more complex. Four provided options are a-> 389   b-> 356   c-> 345   d-> 258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the peculiarity there are $36$ such numbers ie (8 in $12-19$,7 to $23-29$,...1 in $80-89(89)$) in $1-100$ then $28=36-8$ such numbers in $100-200$ ie ($123-129$ have 7... $180-189$have 1) ... And so on ...so we want 100th number so 100=36(total numbers in($1-100$)+28(total numbers in $100-200$)+21(total numbers in ($200-300$)+15(total numbers in $300-400$)  so its the last number of the range $300-400$ which is $389$

Comment: Could you clarify your answer? I am not understanding the method you are using, nor how you reach the answer.

Comment: i am not getting how did you found there are 36 numbers in 1-100 and 28 in 100-200

Comment: Edited any problem now

Comment: marked it correct.

Answer (score 4):

12-19 are sorted; 20, 21, 22 are not. So we have 8 sorted numbers, 3 unsorted (where 1 is the first digit)

23-29 are sorted; 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 are not. So we have 7 sorted numbers, 4 unsorted (where 0 is the first digit)...

And we continue this pattern of decreasing sorted numbers until 89, since the 90's have no sorted number. So 8+7+6+...+1 = 36 sorted numbers.

There is not another sorted number until 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129 (7 sorted)

And the 130's would have 6 sorted, etc... Another 7+6+5....+1 = 28 sorted numbers.

And in the 200's, there will be 7+6+5...+1 = 21 sorted

300's; 6+5+4+...+1 = 15 sorted.

This brings us to the 100th sorted number, since 36 + 28 + 21 + 15 = 100.

So the last sorted number in the 300's, is equal to 389.

Comment: Thanks for the method. But how can we exactly find the 100th sort number???

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: upvote ^^. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

In any permutation of $n$ distinct digits, there is just **one** sequence of strictly increasing digits, thus the number of **combinations** of $n$ distinct digits = # of sorted numbers

There are $\binom92 = 36$ sorted two-digit #s

There are $\binom82 = 28$ sorted three-digit #s starting with $1\to 64$ running total

There are $\binom72 = 21$ sorted three-digit #s starting with $2\to 85$ running total

There are $\binom62 = 15$ sorted three-digit #s starting with $3\to 100$ running total

Thus $389$ should be the hundreth sorted #

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is an easier way to do this, but I broke this up into sets.  For the two digit numbers:

{12, 13, 14, ..., 19} : there are 8 sorted numbers with a leading 1
{23, 24, 25, ..., 29} : there are 7 sorted numbers with a leading 2

Carrying out this logic, there are 8 + 7 + ... + 1 = 36 two digit sorted numbers.

Next, look at three digit sorted numbers.  There are 7 + 6 + ... + 1 = 28 three digit sorted numbers that start with 1, 6 + 5 + ... + 1 = 21 three digit sorted numbers that start with a 2, and 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15 three digit sorted numbers that start with a 3.

So, I got the same answer as Archis - 389

Comment: true blue anil's answer is a better approach